# Grails Helper method/class to be used inside the Service

Tags: grails

I need some advice on design perspective regarding Grails Services.

At some point..I calculate about 5-6 different lists based on ONE object, for example modified, deleted, added people.

I'm not allowed to add anything to the database layer, so domain class is not an option (transient, etc).

These lists are different for each time the method in service is called.

What would be the best way and where to implement: A helper storage class for these lists. I can set them once in service, and get them from another method in service.

Is there a better way when working in the Services? The object to the class should not be created locally inside a method otherwise i don't have access to it later

Comment: services by default are singletons and are injected, so may cause an issue or conflicting list if you have some form of shared list. You could use something like a concurrentHashMap and set a string key and arraySet value. Or rather than service use src/{groovy|java}/{yourpackage}/helperClasses then instantiate them and pass objects on from main call..

Comment: Thanks but it's too much code to post. The question isn't clear enough so better delete it then. @Vahid: yes something like that i was thinking too, whether i should reset the list then after each time. Not enough info on this part, i will have to play a bit with it

Comment: well you may get an idea from this : https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-boselecta-plugin/blob/master/grails-app/services/grails/plugin/boselecta/ClientProcessService.groovy -- you could then bind it to the users session and it would automatically clear out when they leave.. I kind of touched on array session values on this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29801473/to-create-a-session-explicitly-for-first-the-first-time-page-loads-in-grails/